# zf2 move vender to a global directory?

Tags: zend-framework2

I am new to zf2. One thing I noticed is the size of the vender directory.

Can I move the vender dir to another location, i.e, /usr/zf2/vender. In that case, all the users can use the vender directory without keeping a local copy of 18M in size.

Thanks,

ttk

Comment: Are you using [composer](https://getcomposer.org)?

Comment: This skeleton I git from is using composer. Will that matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit ./config/application.config.php feil and change/add a module path of your choosing...

```
// These are various options for the listeners attached to the ModuleManager
'module_listener_options' => array(
    // This should be an array of paths in which modules reside.
    // If a string key is provided, the listener will consider that a module
    // namespace, the value of that key the specific path to that module's
    // Module class.
    'module_paths' => array(
        './module',
        './vendor',
    ),
),
```

I am unsure how composer will react to this though as it follows its own scheme and will probably have some sideeffects.